# Run adb shell on custom device

Tags: android, adb

I have several connected devices via adb :

```
> adb devices
List of devices attached
FA5BBBJ01013    device
00c95491829ca2a1        device
```

When I try to run shell :

```
> adb shell
```

it gives me error :

```
error: more than one device and emulator
```

How I can start shell on custom device without disconnecting other device?

Comment: disconnect one device. it showing you have more than one device cnnected. disconnect non use device,

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot without disconnect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
adb -s 00c95491829ca2a1 shell
```

**From this [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands)**

If multiple emulator/device instances are running, you must specify a target instance when issuing adb commands. To do so, use the -s option in the commands. The usage for the -s option is:

```
adb -s <serialNumber> <command>
```

As shown, you specify the target instance for a command using its adb-assigned serial number. You can use the devices command to obtain the serial numbers of running emulator/device instances. For example:

```
adb -s emulator-5556 install helloWorld.apk
```

Comment: Right answer! Checked just now.

Comment: I am glad that my answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
adb -s < serialNumber > shell
```

Serial number : FA5BBBJ01013  or 00c95491829ca2a1 depending on which one you want to run.

**[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands)**